# How to update dapp contract

Tags: ethereum, truffle, consensys-truffle

How can I update the smartcontracts of my [Truffle](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle) dapp which are deployed in the [Ethereum](https://www.ethereum.org/) blockchain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Great answer found [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2159/guidelines-for-designing-contracts-to-handle-bugfixes).

From [axic](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/664/axic) in [Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/) site:

> Contract code is immutable, the storage is mutable, but you cannot
>   execute code placed into storage, at least for now.
>
> **Bugfixes to contracts**
>
> As for bugfixes, the common pattern is to have proxy or lookup
>   contracts to be a gateway to the real one, which in case of a change
>   or bugfix would be replaced. Replacing it also means losing the old
>   storage contents.
>
> **Keeping storage**
>
> If you want the ability to upgrade code, while keeping storage, you
>   could think of separating storage and logic. Have a dedicated storage
>   contract, which accepts write calls from trusted addresses (e.g. the
>   logic contracts). All important storage should be associated with this
>   one.
>
> **Accessing storage after selfdestruct**
>
> As of today there is no real pruning implemented even in the case of
>   selfdestruct, but that should definitely come in the future. There are
>   several EIPs discussing this.
>
> Even if pruning is implemented, it shouldn't happen in an instant and
>   you should be able to read storage from the last state. It is also
>   planned to have archive nodes to keep states indefinitely -- not sure
>   that is feasible without limitations just by judging at the growth of
>   the blockchain.
>
> **Redeploying at same address**
>
> In short: practically this is not possible. The contract addresses are
>   calculated from the sender and the nonce. The nonce is sequential,
>   there cannot be any gaps and there cannot be duplicates.
>
> In theory it is possible to arrive at the same hash with a different
>   nonce and address combination, but the likelyhood is small.